# Программа полностью игнорирует хэндлер с callback_query

Tags: python, aiogram

Помогите, пожалуйста, решить проблему. Нужно, чтобы эти хэндлеры обрабатывали нажатие на клавишу, но при этом не реагировали ни на какой текст. Как мне кажется, одно из решений - просто использовать callback_query, однако я пришел к следующему результату...

Проблема: Второй и третий хэндлеры программой просто игнорируются, без разницы, что я ввожу в callback_query(Например, "F.text", "F.text.lower()", "F.data", "lambda c: c.data")

Хэндлеры:

```
@router.message(CommandStart())
async def start(message: Message):
    await message.answer(f"Здравствуй, <b>{message.from_user.first_name}</b>\nЧто тебя интересует?", reply_markup=keyboards.main_kb)


    @router.callback_query(F.text.lower() == 'faq')
async def faq(cbq: types.message):
    await cbq.answer("Здесь должны быть Frequently Asked Questions \nСкиньте текст мне")


@router.callback_query(lambda c: c.data == "storeinfo")
async def storeinfo(cbq: types.CallbackQuery):
    await cbq.answer("Здесь должна быть информация о магазине, стикеры, эмодзи и прочая \nфигня может быть засунута сюда")
```

Файл с клавиатурами:

```
from aiogram.types import (
    ReplyKeyboardMarkup,
    KeyboardButton,
    InlineKeyboardMarkup,
    InlineKeyboardButton
)

main_kb = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(
    keyboard=[
        [
            KeyboardButton(text='Покупка', callback_data='purchase'),
            KeyboardButton(text='FAQ', callback_data='faq')
        ],
        [
            KeyboardButton(text='Информация о магазине', callback_data='storeinfo'),
            KeyboardButton(text='Связь с менеджером', callback_data='manager')
        ]
    ],
    resize_keyboard=True
)
```

Comment: У тебя обычная клавиатура, там нет callback_data

Comment: callback_data есть только у инлайн-клавиатуры? Если так, то можно ли как-то сделать, чтобы бот реагировал лишь на нажатие кнопки на обычной клавиатуре, но на сообщение не смотрел. К примеру, если я введу в чат FAQ, он мне ничего не выдаст, но если я нажму на кнопку с тем же названием, он выведет соответствующий текст и т.д.

Comment: Нельзя. Обычная клавиатура - это, по сути, шаблонные фразы. При нажатии на кнопку боту отправляется слово или фраза, которая на ней указана. Это равносильно тому, если это же слово отправить боту вручную